# Basic slider event handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm sitting on a basic jQuery Slider to learn a bit about plugin development in jquery.

What it does:

- it slides from right to left
- when mouse enters the interval is cleared and the animation stops
- when mouse leaves the interval restarts

But here is the problem:

When i constantly enter and leave the slider the animate functions of the slides breaks. the loading animation continues as intended.

i believe its not the best idea that the eventhandling is hearing on `mouseenter` and `leave`. thought about buttons that handle this things but maybe its something other completely wrong / stupid here. :)

have a look here: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/e57fnsmo/4/):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to clear your Timeout and stopping Slider before `init()` (start) again

I updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pleinx/e57fnsmo/6/)

**Changes:**

```
var interval, timeout;

function stopSlider()   {
    console.log("function: stopSlider");        
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    clearInterval(interval);        
}

$('.slides').on('mouseenter', function()    {
    stopSlider();
}).on('mouseleave', function()  {
    stopSlider();
    timeout = setTimeout(init, pause);
});

function startSlider()   {
    // just a tip
    // $('.loading').animate({"width": "0"}, 0); // makes no sense, use instead .css()
    $('.loading').css('width', '0'); 
    ...
}
```

Comment: Wow. This helped a lot. I need to read about that clearTimeout function and when to use it. So this means basically that timeout is fired and fired and fired again and not one is cleared. but the behaviour is strange. i would assume that the timeouts are getting stacked and sequentially processed.

Comment: You're welcome :) Correctly. Timeout fired again and again. The Base Problem was you go first in with your mouse `mouseenter` which starts already new timeout which also starts a new interval (new procress id `2`). Now you do trigger `mouseleave` and cleared only the first (initialized procress id `1`) interval, but not the interval which we start before (timeout with 3sec).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clearing the interval , you could try using flags to control the Stop and Go of your animation. Using ClearInterval to stop an animation and resume it by creating a new Interval is not control over it. Something like the below might prove useful to your case and help you at a different direction. :

```html
<div id='mySlider' style='width:200px;height:40px;background-color:blue;'></div>
<script>
  var mySlider = document.getElementById('mySlider');
  var isOver = true;

  mySlider.addEventListener('mouseenter' , function(){
    isOver = false;
  });
  
  mySlider.addEventListener('mouseout' , function(){
    isOver = true;
  });

  var myID = setInterval(function(){
    if(isOver === false)
      mySlider.style.width = parseInt(mySlider.style.width) + 1 + "px";
  },10);

</script>
```